# In existing iOS app i need to integrate screen casting feature to all Smart TV

Tags: ios, swift, mirroring, smart-tv, screencast

I have video streaming App so, In existing iOS app i need to integrate screen casting feature to all Smart TV and devices like Chromecast, Roku, Amazon Fire TV, XBOX, Samsung TV, Vizio TV, Sony TV, LG TV etc, So how can achieve this within my app

Comment: best way is use/integrate google cast in project for video steaming.

Comment: Will it support all major smart TV & device, or it only will support to google chromecast

Comment: only support to google chrome cast(most smart tv supported to chrome cast).

Comment: Airplay comes for free with AVPlayer.  You can add Chromecast from Google as suggested; That should cover most common devices.  If there are other devices that don't work with either of those then you will need to find an SDK for them

Comment: @Paulw11, i don't play audio or video in my app. i just want to mirroring my app screen to other screen (apple tv and samsung tv). how can share app screen to other screen without audio/video playing ?

Comment: Apple TV is handled through AirPlay and screen mirroring on the device for a smart Tv that doesn't support AirPlay then you would need to look for an SDK for that device.